# How to save multiple listbox value into single textfile C#

Tags: c#, list, foreach, listbox, text-files

what I have right now are two listbox which are lstItem and lstQty and I want to save both value into single textfile.

```
lstItem   |   lstQty
Chicken   |     3
Fish      |     2
Lamb      |     1
```

I want this value saved into textfile like this:

```
Chicken | 3
Fish | 2
Lamb | 1
```

Instead of:

```
Chicken
Fish
Lamb
3
2
1
```

These is my codes:

```
string receiptFile = @"D:\VisualStudio2012\SalesDetails.txt";

StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(receiptFile, true);

List<string> totalSales = new List<string>();
foreach (object item in lboItem.Items)
{
   totalSales.Add(item as string);
   file2.WriteLine(item);
}
foreach (object item2 in lboQty.Items)
{
   totalSales.Add(item2 as string);
   file2.WriteLine(item2);
}
file2.Close();
```

I know why it shows in textfile like what i mentioned above. It happens because i have no idea how to make it like what i want. Thank you in advance to anyone that can solve this.

Comment: What you need is not a `foreach` but a for loop. Loop through a single `for (var i =0;i< lboitem.lenght;i++)` loop and then pick up the item at index `i` from both the list like `var item = lboItem[i].value; var qty = lboqty[i].value; and then write the values to the file `file2.Writeline("{0}|{1}", item, qty)` beware that the elements in list 1 should be equal to elements in list 2

Comment: I cant insert `length` after listbox name. Can you answer it through coding? Thanks @Nilesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of your two loops you need only one and during this one loop you just need to concatenate values from both listboxes and write them to file.

Something like this:

```
int itemsCount = Math.Min(lboItem.Items.Count, lboQty.Items.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
{
    string item = "";
    if (i < lboItem.Items.Count)
        item = lboItem.Items[i].ToString();

    item += " | ";

    if (i < lboQty.Items.Count)
        item += lboQty.Items[i].ToString();

    totalSales.Add(item);
    file2.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I'm not sure why do you need `totalSales` list here - but it's up to your logic.

Also note - there is check here for the situation when sizes of listboxes are not equal. If your listboxes sizes are guarantied to be equal - this check is redundant you can simplify this code snippet to

```
int itemsCount = lboItem.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
{
    string item = string.Format("{0} | {1}", lboItem.Items[i], lboQty.Items[i]);
    totalSales.Add(item);
    file2.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is too perfect. Thanks @Andy Korneyev

Answer (score 1):

If both listboxes always have the same number of items, maybe this helps you:

```
string receiptFile = @"D:\VisualStudio2012\SalesDetails.txt";
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(receiptFile, true);
for(int i=0; i < lboItem.Items.Count; i++)
{
  file2.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | {1}", lboItem.Items[i].ToString(), lboQty.Items[i].ToString()));
}
file2.Close();
```

I didn't realize the purpose of `totalSales`. If you need it, you can add it inside the for loop.